# SQL to Oracle SQL Conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help me convert this code into Oracle SQL? Or please give me direction as to why this is throwing an error on Oracle SQL?

```
declare @PropertyName varchar(64)
set @PropertyName= 'ESRegion'
select PD.PropertyId,
PD.PropertyName,
convert(varchar(255), v.Value ) DisplayValue
from Property_Dictionary PD WITH(READUNCOMMITTED) 
inner join CorpTax_LookupDefinition l on l.Lookupkey = pd.ReferenceType
join MDTable md on l.DataDictionaryTypeId = md.TableGUID 
join ValueChar v on 
(
v.TableID = md.TableID 
and v.AttributeID = l.DisplayAttributeId 
)
where PD.DataTypeid = 7
and PD.PropertyName = @PropertyName
```

Comment: And what error would that be?

Comment: It's throwing an error because your syntax is completely wrong... have you tried to convert this to Oracle? What went wrong when you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select PD.PropertyId, PD.PropertyName, cast(v.value as varchar(255)) as DisplayValue
from Property_Dictionary PD inner join
     CorpTax_LookupDefinition l
     on l.Lookupkey = pd.ReferenceType join
     MDTable md
     on l.DataDictionaryTypeId = md.TableGUID join
     ValueChar v
      on v.TableID = md.TableID and
         v.AttributeID = l.DisplayAttributeId 
where PD.DataTypeid = 7 and PD.PropertyName = 'ESRegion'
```

As mentioned elsewhere, this is a bit different.  It will invoke a read lock on the table.  If you care about that, then you need to research different Oracle options for locking.  I changed CONVERT to CAST.  It is not clear what the type of v.value is, but this should work.  (For some types, to_char() would be better.)

I also put the variable directly into the query.  If you want variables, then you are outside the score of just SQL, and into the realms of PL/SQL and TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is non-SQL here.  Do you mean T/SQL to PL/SQL?  Also, I wouldn't think WITH(READUNCOMITTED) would be allowed in Oracle as that is not read uncommitted is not allowed in Oracle (you could change the transaction isolation if you need the ability to do dirty reads).  Finally, I don't think convert is used right.

Comment: You can't do dirty reads in Oracle. Period.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, more a comment...

Comment: @Ben - you can flag for mod if you like, who may be persuaded to convert `:)`

Comment: Ben, he did ask for direction not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL*Plus, you could do the following:

```
define PropertyName='ESRegion'
SELECT PD.PropertyId, PD.PropertyName, v.Value DisplayValue 
  FROM Property_Dictionary PD 
         INNER JOIN CorpTax_LookupDefinition l 
                 ON l.Lookupkey = pd.ReferenceType 
               JOIN MDTable md ON l.DataDictionaryTypeId = md.TableGUID
               JOIN ValueChar v ON ( v.TableID = md.TableID  AND
                                     v.AttributeID = l.DisplayAttributeId  )
 WHERE PD.DataTypeid = 7 
   AND PD.PropertyName = '&PropertyName';
```

DEFINE replaces the DECLARE and SET in your original code. You'd then use the DEFINE'd variable in your query.